# Replace C macro for a function call with a C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to replace this preprocessor macro:

```
#define AL_CALL(a) do { a;                              \
                        ALenum e = alGetError();        \
                        if(e != AL_NO_ERROR)            \
                            UtilitySoundNode::printALError(e,__FILE__, __LINE__); \
                       } while(0)
```

with a C++ template? If it is possible, will make any sense to do it (pros/cons - overhead/debugging)?

**Note:**
Basically I am wondering if there is an elegant way to handle this kind of error handling in C++.

**EDIT:**
Of course I made a mistake **a** is a function call. As one may guess it is a function call with parameters of a OpenAL function.

```
AL_CALL(someAlFunction(param1, param2))
```

**NOTE:** 
Somebody decided to edit the macro and make it nicer but I'd prefer to keep the original one too. So here it is:

```
#define AL_CALL(a) {a; ALenum e = alGetError();if(e != AL_NO_ERROR)PUtilitySoundNode::printALError(e,__FILE__, __LINE__);}
```

Comment: What type can `a` be?

Comment: What could `a` be that would make the statement `a;` make any sense?  It is hard t answer this question without knowing that.  Perhaps you mean `a();` and it is a function pointer?  If that is the case then a simple inline-functon is all that is needed, unless you need functons with different signatures.

Comment: Is that really a c macro? (`UtilitySoundNode::printALError`!)

Comment: @user3490458 : I guess he means a C-Preprocessor macro - you can put anything you like in a macro, as far as the preprocessor is concerned, the preprocessor does not check syntax, that is done by the compiler after expansion.  I edited the text and tags to correct that.

Comment: @AnonMail It is a function call. I am sorry for failing to point this out.

Answer (score 4):

One problem here seems to be that the "a" can be some arbitrary function (with parameters) which sets the error code returned by alGetError().

That can be rewritten to C++ by using a functor object. To pass the arguments (and object instance if necessary) `std::bind` or `boost::bind` can be used (note that to bind reference args the `std::ref`/`boost::ref` is necessary).

However, if you'd want to still have the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` passed the the printError() that C++ template still would need to be called by a macro which will pass those to the template. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are only expanded by the preprocessor, so there is no way around using a macro for them.

But the macro could be much simpler then and most of the work can be done in the C++ template (which has many advantages e.g. for debugging, because in most debuggers you cannot step into a macro).

EDIT: adding the code as an example:

```
template<typename T>
void ALcallAndCheck(T c, const char *file, size_t line)
{
    c();
    ALenum e = alGetError();
    if(e != AL_NO_ERROR)
        UtilitySoundNode::printALError(e, file, line); \
}

#define AL_CALL(a) ALcallAndCheck(a, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Then, instead of

```
AL_CALL(SomeFunction(2, refAttr));
```

the call will become:

```
AL_CALL(std::bind(SomeFunction, 2, std::ref(refAttr)));
```

EDIT 2:
The previous indeed does not work with expressions, which the original macro allows. To work also for expressions, the macro can be altered to:

```
#define AL_CALL(a) ALcallAndCheck([&]{ (a); }, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

That will create a lambda which will evaluate anything that comes into the macro. Then even the `std::bind` is not necessary and it can be called directly as:

```
AL_CALL(SomeFunction(2, refAttr));
AL_CALL(SomeOtherFunction1()+SomeOtherFunction2(8));
```

Comment: Nice that you bring up `std::bind`, (this is not a comment on my upvote).

Comment: Does std::bind create any overhead? Would you use it (`std::bind`) and that template in a performance critical code (e.g. a render loop)? As an alternative I am starting to think about an error handling with a `goto` (although I am not quite sure if it will work).

Comment: @axalis Unfortunately I'll need to pass any C++11 features or boost.

Answer (score 2):

No, the use of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` pretty well require the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Note that using a template instead of a macro does not produce an exact analog. The macro defined in your question allows `a` to represent a statement as well as an expression. A template does not have that kind of flexibility. The template defined below assumes `a` is a non-`void` expression.

There is no standard way to implicitly inject a function caller's file name and line number without the caller passing in that information to the called function. A preprocessor macro allows a means to make the syntax appear to be implicit injection, when in fact the information is being passed.

```
template <typename T>
void AL_CALL (T a, const char *file, int line) {
    ALenum e = alGetError();
    if(e != AL_NO_ERROR)
        UtilitySoundNode::printALError(e, file, line);
}

#define AL_CALL(X) AL_CALL((X), __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

You may be able to use system specific facilities (e.g., [`CaptureStackBackTrace` + `SymFromAddr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`backtrace` + `backtrace_symbols`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html)) to get approximately the same information implicitly, but it may require debugging symbols to be present, and inline functions may not produce the expected output.

Comment: This does not seem to work if the function passed as the X parameter does return void ("`could not deduce template argument for 'T' from 'void'`") - that's why I was using `std::bind()` in my response.

Comment: @E.Maskovsky: My answer already stated my assumptions. Your solution still does not resolve the general problem of the original macro allowing the argument to be a statement (e.g., an `if` statement).

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice that. And yes, the macro also allows expressions, which  the std::bind solution does not allow (but that could be perhaps solved by using lambda in the support macro)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class A>
void al_call(A&&a){
  ALenum e = a();
  if(e != AL_NO_ERROR)
    UtilitySoundNode::printALError(e,__FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

Use:

```
al_call( [&]{ return bob(); });
```

Instead of:

```
AL_CALL( bob() )
```

The line/file info is not useful above.

So

```
template<class A>
void al_call(A&&a, char const*file, unsigned line){
  ALenum e = a();
  if(e != AL_NO_ERROR)
    UtilitySoundNode::printALError(e,file, line);
}
#define AL_CALL(...) al_call([&]()mutable{return __VA_ARGS__;}, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

and it is almost a drop in replacement.

Comment: (of course meant expanded to the correct values, they will indeed be expanded, but AFAIK not to the caller file and line)

Comment: @Yakk, Unfortunately it turn's out I'll have to support GCC 3.x.x so Lambdas and such modern stuff are out of question. So is there any solution that doesn't require C++11 or boost?